# A hand of cards contains 5 cards - probability

Tags: probability

A hand of cards consists of five cards drawn at random without replacement from a 52 card deck. I must take an unordered hand of 5 cards. The sample space is the set of all unordered hands. How would I write this sample space down with correct notation? I must also write down the number of sample points in the sample space.

Also - A is the event that four cards in the hand have the same face value (four 2's, four 3's etc.). I must find the number of points in the event A and assuming all sample points are equally likely to occur, I have to find P(A).

Can anyone provide me some help with this?

Comment: You can mark the answer correct if it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Number of ways to get an unordered hand of 5 cards is:
$$^{52}C_5$$
Since the same face value of four cards can occur only 13 times(once for each face)hence:

$$P(A)={{13*(^{48}C_1)}\over ^{52}C_5}$$
The reasoning is that we first **choose 4 cards** having the same face value(13 ways) and then **choose the fifth card** from the remaining 48 cards($^{48}C_1$ ways).

Comment: Would 52C5 work for cards that are not replaced? Also, would that value be the number of sample points in the sample space?

Comment: Yes 52C5 is for cards that are not replaced. If cards were replaced you would have 52*52*52*52*52.

Comment: Yes this value is the number of sample points in the sample space.

Comment: Would I just do 13*48 to find the number of sample points in A and then divide that by the total number of points in the sample space (52C5) for the probability?

Comment: Yes! That is also how you can do it.